# Google Apps Free - Multiple domains?

Tags: domain, google-workspace, google-app-engine

I use Google Apps free right now with one domain (`example.com`). Now I have bought another domain (`example2.com`). Do I need to create a new Google Apps account to use example2.com or can I continue to use the new domain with my first Google Apps account?

I have verified with my first Google Apps account that I am the owner of example2.com by entering a `TXT` DNS record. So it looks alright and it says that it's verified.

I'm wondering because I want to use example2.com with Google App Engine but when I try to connect my application with example2.com I get a message saying:

> Google Apps Administrator Control Panel has not been enabled by the administrator of the domain @example2.com.

It seems that I have to create a new Google Apps account for domain example2.com? I was hoping I could have all my domains administered from one Google Apps account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't add your secondary domain as "domain" you have to add it as a "domain alias" for it to work.

See this forum [thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/2EUO5-gpepE) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can add the second domain to the first account [from this link](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182452).

If you want to work from a single gmail-account, you can add mail-aliases to the primary gmail-account. If you do this and you send a mail using the second domain, Gmail adds header info about the primary gmail account in it.

Comment: Yes I've read that information. But it doesn't help me with Google App Engine.